# Problem with for loop in Python variable row is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I am creating a large program with `mysql-connector-python` but it gets stuck on one error that *variable row is not defined* after using *if-else* statement in `for loop`.

**Here is my portion of code where i am getting error:**

```
elif question == 'login' or 'login'.upper():
        email1 = input("Your email: ")
        passw1 = input("Your password: ")
        if '@' and '.' or '.com' in email:
            if len(passw1) > 5:
                mycursor.execute("USE register;")
                mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM id;")
       # ------------------------------------------------#
                for row, col in mycursor.fetchall():    #|
                    pass                                #|    Here is the line which is affecting my code
                if email1 in row:                       #|   
                    if passw1 in col:                   #|
       # ------------------------------------------------#
                        print("Successfuly signed in!!")
                        break
```

**And here is the full code:**

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="register"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
# OTP
OTP = 1234
# asking to choose
question = input("Would you like to login or signup?? ")
# sign up
while True:
    if question == 'signup':
        email = input("--------------------------\nYour email: ")
        passw = input("Your password: ")
        confirm_pass = input("Confirm password: ")
        mycursor.execute("USE register;")
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM id;")
        for row, col in mycursor.fetchall():
            pass
        if email in row:
            if passw in col:
                print("Already logged in!!")
        elif '@' and '.' or '.com' in email:
            if passw == confirm_pass:
                if len(passw) > 5:
                    print("----------------------------\nSuccessfuly registered!")
                    mycursor.execute("USE register;")
                    query = "INSERT INTO id(email, passw) VALUES(%s,%s);"
                    args = (email, passw)
                    mycursor.execute(query, args)
                    mydb.commit()
                    break
                else:
                    print("Your password is too short")

            else:
                print("Passwords didn't match!")

        else:
            print("wrong email")

     # login condition
    elif question == 'login' or 'login'.upper():
        email1 = input("Your email: ")
        passw1 = input("Your password: ")
        if '@' and '.' or '.com' in email:
            if len(passw1) > 5:
                mycursor.execute("USE register;")
                mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM id;")
                for row, col in mycursor.fetchall():
                    pass
                if email1 in row:
                    if passw1 in col:
                        print("Successfuly signed in!!")
                        break
                    else:
                        print("wrong email or password!!")
                        forgot_pass = input("Forgot password? \nYes/no ")
                        if forgot_pass == 'yes':
                            print("Yes")
                        elif forgot_pass == 'no':
                            print("No")
                        else:
                            print("Blah blah blah")
                else:
                    print("wrong email or password!!")
                    forgot_pass = input("Forgot password? \nYes/no ")
                    if forgot_pass == 'yes':
                        print("We have send an OTP at your email")
                        enter_OTP = int(input("Type OTP within 1 minute "))
                        if enter_OTP == OTP:
                            change_passw = input("Type new password ")
                        else:
                            print("Wrong OTP!")
                            break
                    elif forgot_pass == 'no':
                        print("No")
                    else:
                        print("Blah blah blah")
            else:
                print("Your password is too short")
        else:
            print("wrong email")
    else:
        print("Blah blah blah...")
```

Comment: Is the above code formatted exactly similar to what you have on your machine?

Comment: Yep ! just edit it and make elif to if in the first line as it is a piece of code ... or should i mention my whole code?

Comment: Well, indent is **very** important in python, it defines scopes. Check the `for` loop and the following `if`

Comment: I suppose my indent is right. Or wait. Let me share you my whole code...

Comment: Do you use an IDE or Text Editor ?

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but take care: `question == 'login' or 'login'.upper():` is not equivalent to "question equals 'login', or it equals 'LOGIN'". It's equivalent to "question equals 'login', or the boolean value of the string 'LOGIN' is True". All non-empty strings are true in a boolean context, so that conditional will always evaluate to True, regardless of `question`'s value.

Comment: ` if email1 in row:` at this point you're not in the previous loop, so `row` is out of scope.

Comment: So how to solve this? @blueteeth

Comment: While the commenters talking about scope are on the right track, keep in mind that a for loop block does not have its own scope. It's perfectly valid to do `for x in range(10): <newline> <indent> pass; <newline> print(x)`. If the loop iterated at least once, `x` still exists after the loop ends.

Comment: So can you please edit this and share through an answer? @Kevin

Comment: Are you sure `mycursor.fetchall()` returns something?

Comment: Let me check that again...

Comment: which mysql via pip is it you have installed... somehow it can't find the right version of mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference a variable `row` outside of the for loop scope.

```python
for row, col in mycursor.fetchall():
    # notice that row and passw1 are now indented inside the for loop block
    if email1 == row and passw1 == col:
        print("Successfuly signed in!!")
        break
```

See [python-scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) for more details.

Comment: Now also it says row not defined. Why?

Comment: Terminology nitpick: For loops don't have their own scope. Perhaps it would be better to say "you reference a variable `row` outside of the for loop block". In any case I agree that moving the `if` inside the loop is a good idea.